# Replace JSON object in array dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have a color picker component that upon selecting a color adds a `JSON` object with the `rgba` value to an already existing `array` in `this.state.style.colors`.

This is currently achieved with

```
onColorHandler = (color: any, index: number) => {
    let colors;
    if (index === 0) {
        colors = [
            {
                name: 'Background',
                color: {
                    rgb: color.rgb,
                },
            },
            this.state.style.colors[1],
            this.state.style.colors[2],
        ];
    } else if (index === 1) {
        colors = [
            this.state.style.colors[0],
            {
                name: 'Heading',
                color: {
                    rgb: color.rgb,
                },
            },
            this.state.style.colors[2],
        ];
    } 
    this.setState(
        {
            style: {
                colors,
            },
        }
    );
};
```

However well this may work, it's not very reusable. For example if I wanted to add a third `object` to the `array`, I would have to update the function to support another `index` with the `name` value.

I have searched for a way to add the `objects` to the `array` dynamically but have come up short in a solution.

Any suggestions?

I only have access to `index` which could be used to lookup the object in the current `this.state.style.colors` as that contains all the necessary information regarding the `name` and `prevState`.

Thank you kindly for any assistance or direction

Comment: The pattern for inserting in an array is shown [here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#inserting-and-removing-items-in-arrays)

Comment: Thank you @Wyck. Really helpful link that I will be brushing up on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

In this example, the blue color of the index 2 will be replaced by the tomato color according to the value of the index variable.

```js
const index = 2
const array = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange']
const color = 'tomato'
const output = array.splice(index, 1, color)
console.log(array)
```

In your react ap context you could do the same by passing by mutating a clone array and set its new value to the state, something like this

```
onColorHandler = (color: any, index: number) => {
  const colors = this.state.style.colors.slice() // clone array

  colors.splice(index, 1, color) // mutate array

  this.setState({
    style: {
      colors
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mario. Put me in the right direction, I only had to grab the name field to keep the current json structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can just set the element at the index in the array using bracket notation.

```
let colors = [...this.state.style.colors];
colors[index] = {
    name: 'Background',
    color: {
        rgb: color.rgb,
    }
}
this.setState(
    {
        style: {
            colors,
        },
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `this.state.style.colors` is somehow filled and you don't need to change the `name` property in each `color`.

```
onColorHandler = (color: any, index: number) => {
    let colors = [...this.state.style.colors]; //create new colors array
    colors[index].color.rgb = color.rgb;
    this.setState(
        {
            style: {
                colors,
            },
        }
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
onColorHandler = (color: any, index: number) => {
    const colors = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.style.colors)) // deep copy
    let newColor = colors[index]
    newColor.name = ['Background', 'Heading'][index] || 'default color name'
    newColor.color = color.rgb
    this.setState({style: { colors }})
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the situation that you are in. If you are planning to use the index of the array to get the object, then I would just create a map object to connect my function with some what dynamic nature. First of I will create something like:

```
const mappingObject = [
   "Background",
   "Heading"
]
```

I will then tune up the function to act on the basis of this object. Like:

```
onColorHandler = (color: any, index: number) => {
    const colors = [...this.state.style.colors];
    colors[index] = {
        name: mappingObject[index] || "default", // undefined fallback key as default
        color: {
            rgb: color.rgb,
        }
    }
    this.setState({
        style: {colors},
    });
};
```

On your next entry, You just have to edit the mappingObject and the next item will be handled on that index number. no need to extend `if-else` statements